# Count of particular day inbetween 2 dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, count

I want to count number of times a particular day comes in between 2 dates using pure java script. Please let me know the logic to find that.

for example 
1. between 01-01-2018 and 25-03-2018 day 15 is coming 3 times(15-01-2018,15-02-2018,15-03-2018)
2. between 25-01-2018 and 10-03-2018 day 14 is coming 1 time(14-02-2018)

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. If you want to solve this yourself, you should get a piece of paper and a pencil and write out the steps you would take to do this by hand. Once you have an understanding of the steps, then you can translate them into code.

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard, just have a DateInterval, loop, check date, increment counter. What have you tried though?